# Write a meta-function returning a type from a type-list that has a typedef of a given type in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have run into a scenario in which I have a list of classes in a variadic template list, and, given a type (`Target_`), I wish to find the class in the list (`ContainingClass_`) that `typedef`s `Target_` as `ContainingClass_::Class`.

Here is my current, brute force implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <uint32_t ID_, class Class_>
struct ContainingClass
{
    using Class = Class_;
    static constexpr uint32_t id() { return ID_; }
};

// Get the index of a type in a type list, or -1 on error (So that we only get the important static_assert).
template <typename Target_, typename ...List_>
struct IndexOf : std::integral_constant<int, -1> {};

template <typename Target_, typename NotTarget_, typename ...List_>
struct IndexOf<Target_, NotTarget_, List_...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + IndexOf<Target_, List_...>::value> {};

template <typename Target_, typename ...List_>
struct IndexOf<Target_, Target_, List_...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

// Check if a type exists in a typelist.
template <typename Target_, typename... List_>
struct TypeExists;

template <typename Target_>
struct TypeExists<Target_> : std::false_type {};

template <typename Target_, typename... List_>
struct TypeExists<Target_, Target_, List_...> : std::true_type {};

template <typename Target_, typename NotTarget_, typename... List_>
struct TypeExists<Target_, NotTarget_, List_...> : TypeExists<Target_, List_...> {};

// **THE META-FUNCTION THAT THE QUESTION IS ABOUT**
// Find the ContaingClass that typedefs Target_ as "Class" inside of it.
template <class Target_, class ...ContainingClasses_>
struct ContainingClassFinder
{
    static_assert(TypeExists<Target_, typename ContainingClasses_::Class...>::value, "No ContainingClass found for Target_.");
    using ContainingClass = typename std::tuple_element<IndexOf<Target_, typename ContainingClasses_::Class...>::value, 
                                                        std::tuple<ContainingClasses_...>>::type;
};

using namespace std;

// Use the meta function to return the id of the ContainingClass that contains a type.
template <class Target_, class ...ContainingClasses_>
uint32_t get_containing_id(ContainingClasses_...)
{
    return ContainingClassFinder<Target_, ContainingClasses_...>::ContainingClass::id();
}

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};
struct Test {};
struct NonExistent {};

int main()
{
    // Prove that the right class was found be printing its ID out.
    // Prints 2.
    cout << get_containing_id<Test>(ContainingClass<0, Foo>{}, ContainingClass<1, Bar>{}, ContainingClass<2, Test>{}) << endl;
    // Causes static_assert.
    //cout << get_containing_id<NonExistent>(ContainingClass<0, Foo>{}, ContainingClass<1, Bar>{}, ContainingClass<2, Test>{}) << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem with this is that it depends on `std::tuple` and does two linear searches: one for the existence check (using the first helper meta-function) and one to get the type (using `std::tuple_element`).

**I would Ideally like to get all of this in one go, with no need for the two helper meta-functions and `std::tuple`**; is that practical? If not, any improvements to my implementation would be appreciated.

**NOTE:**

**1. This meta-function will be used as an implementation detail of library; Boost is not an option.**

**2. The result of the meta-function should be a type, specifically that of the containing type in which the target type was found in. Getting the id() of the class is just a simple way to show that the meta-function is working.**

**3. By meta-function, I am referring to a templated struct, like the ones defined in `<type_traits>`**

Comment: Instead of reinventing, maybe have a look at Boost.Hana?

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for reminding me; I forgot to mention that this is part of a library, and boost is simply not an option.

Comment: See my updated answer: compiles and works as intended (by me at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following solution?

No `std::tuple` and, if I'm not wrong, only one linear search.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

template <uint32_t, class Class_>
struct ContainingClass
 { using Class = Class_; };

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};
struct Test {};

template <typename, typename ...>
struct getContType;

template <typename T>
struct getContType<T>
 { using type = void; };

template <typename T, typename CC0, typename ... CCs>
struct getContType<T, CC0, CCs...>
 { using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T,
         typename CC0::Class>::value, CC0,
         typename getContType<T, CCs...>::type>::type; };

int main()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<ContainingClass<2, Test>,
                 getContType<Test, ContainingClass<0, Foo>,
                 ContainingClass<1, Bar>, ContainingClass<2, Test>>::type
                 >::value, "!");

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: This looks promising, but getting the id was just to show that the right type was found. The meta-function should have a type result, specifically that of the containing type in which the target type was found.

Comment: @rationalcoder - I see... well... a function can return an object of a type; not a type; I've modified my solution to return an object of type `ContainingClass<2, Test>`; if you only interested in type, I suppose you should create a struct with a type in it, not a function.

Comment: Ahh, the issue here is in the wording. By meta-function, I am essentially referring to a templated struct, as in those defined in type_traits. I will update my question to make that clear. I mean it in the same sense as this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY

Comment: It is there now. It is in the note at the bottom. If you check the comments in the code, I had labeled `ContainingClassFinder` as the meta-function in question.

Comment: @rationalcoder - not sure to understand but... added a `struct getContType`; it's whats you're looking for? Added a second `static_assert()` in `main()` to check it.

Comment: Actually, yes. The solution I had in mind would be just your `getContType` struct (meta-function). Just those three structs at the bottom are all I was looking for. If you distill it down to just those three, this will be the accepted answer. It is rather elegant too; I failed at doing the same thing before coming up with the original solution. I see what I did wrong now. Thank you!

Comment: @rationalcoder - you're wellcome; solution semplified

Answer (score 1):

[Update] This is working for me:

```
// marker for not-found types
struct none {
};

// fwd declaration
template <typename Target_,typename ...List_> struct scanner;

template <
  typename Target_,
  typename Head_, typename ...List_
>
struct scanner<Target_, Head_, List_...> {

  using found_type=typename std::conditional<
   std::is_same<Target_, Head_>::value, // or any other predicate
   Head_,
   // if not, search further
   typename scanner<Target_, List_...>::found_type
  >::type;
  // were are going to reset it anyway if in the end the found_type==none
  static constexpr int value=
     std::is_same<Target_, Head_>::value
   ? 0
   : scanner<Target_, List_...>::value+1
  ;
};

// need a recursion stopper for the scanner here.
template <typename Target_>
struct scanner<Target_> {
  using found_type=none;
  // were are going to reset it anyway if in the end the found_type==none
  static constexpr int value=-1;

};

template <typename Target, typename... List>
struct ContainingClassFinder {
private:
  using result=scanner<Target, List...>;
public:
  static constexpr int value=
      std::is_same<typename result::found_type, none>::value
    ? -1
    : result::value
  ;
  using found_type=typename std::enable_if<
     false==std::is_same<typename result::found_type, none>::value,
     typename result::found_type
  >::type;
};

/// brief test
struct dummy {

};

using good=ContainingClassFinder<
  int,
  long, dummy, int, char
>;
static_assert(std::is_same<int, good::found_type>::value, "Oops - good type failing");
static_assert(good::value==2, "Oops - good index failing");


using bad_notfound=ContainingClassFinder<
  int,
  long, dummy, float, char
>;
static_assert(bad_notfound::value==-1, "Ooops - bad type failing index");

// this should create a compilation error due to std::enable_if with a false condition
using non_existing=typename bad_notfound::found_type; // yeap, it does cause compilation error
```

Comment: This looks like my original attempt that I failed at, haha. I will mess around with it for a minute and see if it suits my needs.

Comment: @rationalcoder Updated/upgraded to something that works (still as an example, can't assess the suitability for your purposes)